# Vector of values from the interval in binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am working with binary trees and what I want is to make a vector with elements that are actually values of the nodes whose are keys between two already given ones. See the code and try to understand :

```
        vector<ValueType> MakeVector ( vector<ValueType> &v, Node* first, Node* last, Node* temp) const
{
    if( temp != 0 && temp->_key >= first->_key && temp->_key <= last->_key )
    {
        MakeVector(v, first, last, temp->_left);
        v.push_back(temp->_value);
        makeVector(v, first, last, temp->_right);

    }
}
vector<ValueType> from_to(KeyType a, KeyType b) const
{
    vector<ValueType> v;
    Node* c (FindMaxSmallerThan(b, _root));  //These functions are working fine
    if( c == 0 ) return v;
    Node* d (FindMinBiggerThan(a, _root));
    if( d == 0 ) return v;
    if(d->_key > c->_key) return v;
    MakeVector( v, d, c, c); /*Here is where my program crashes and it says that I   used  an ilegal pointer :/ */
    return v;
}
```

Comment: it is a mistake I made when translating it from my native language to English :) I have just edited it. Thanks :)

Comment: OK. So in your binary tree, a left child has a smaller or equal; and a right child has a greater or equal key than the own key?

Comment: I think that after you found `c` and `d` you need to go up in the tree to find the common (non-direct) parent. Use this as the starting node (4th argument to `MakeVector`)

Comment: Keys in binary tree are never equal, temp is an iterating node and I included equation because of the possible case that there is only one key between a and b keys so that the vector would have only one element which is the value of that key.

Comment: Hmm....seems like a good advertisement for the library collections. `std::vector<ValueType> values{your_multiset.lower_bound(lower_key), your_multiset.upper_bound(upper_key)};`

Comment: @leemes how can I find efficiently their parent?

Comment: @JerryCoffin That assumes iterators. I don't think that his Binary Tree uses such, as it would require additional code (remember that two consecutive nodes in the "virtual sequence" can be arbitrarily far away in the Binary Tree like here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AVLtreef.svg the nodes 50 and 54)

Comment: @NickyName Do your nodes have a depth stored? (i.e. how many nodes lie on the path to the root)

Comment: no, this is not AVL tree. It is just a binary tree, which can be unbalansed.

Comment: @leemes: You missed Jerry's point: the whole tree can be replaced by a `std::map` (or `std::multimap` if multiple equal keys are allowed).

Comment: but I cannot figure out where do I have illegal pointer ...  I was just using Inorder to reach every node. It is not working when I use a _root as a first value of temp either. :/

Comment: @NickyName: Does your tree nodes hold back pointers to the parent? If it doesn't, consider adding them, as that will help you in this problem (and others, like iteration driven from outside of the container).

Comment: yeah, the do... But it doesn't help much.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I assume that he writes an own tree because he has to (assignment) or wants to do this, not because he needs one. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @NickyName I never said you use AVL trees. But I guess the image shows how your binary tree looks like, right? AVL trees are binary trees with balancing, so they still are binary trees, and this image was the best I could find quickly ;) Because if they look like this, your helper function doesn't work. Consider the range [23, 54] in the image: You would then start from the root, visit both left and child node, but don't further look at them because they are already outside of the range!

Comment: I agree with you. That is why I tried something else. You can see the code below, I'd like to have ur opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected it now thanks to your advices. I think that this might work, but still not so sure.

```
     vector<ValueType> MakeVector ( vector<ValueType> &v, Node* node, Node* lower, Node* upper) const
{
    if( lower->_key == upper->_key )
    {
        v.push_back(lower->_value);
        return v;
    }
    if( node->_parent != 0 && maximum(node->_parent)->_key >= upper->_key)
    inorderVector (v,node->_parent, lower, upper);
    else if( node->_parent != 0)
    MakeVector(v, node->_parent, lower, upper);
    else MakeVector(v, node, lower, upper);
    return v;
}
```

And the InordeVector looks like this:

```
    void inorderVector (vector<ValueType> &v, Node* parent, Node* lower, Node* upper)     const
    {
      if( parent != 0 )
    {
    inorderVector(v, parent->_left, lower, upper);
    if( parent->_key >= lower->_key && parent->_key <= upper->_key )
    v.push_back(parent->_value);
    inorderVector(v, parent->_right, lower, upper);
    }
    return;
    }
```

I choose Inorder because the vector has to be sorted. This way, all the nodes that are key-bigger than our upper bound will be ignored.